# Generated DH key is too big

Tags: android, bouncycastle, dhcp

I'm trying to generate DH key pair where public key has 2048 bit of length, but everytime it's bigger

My code is

```
private static BigInteger g = new BigInteger("1234567890");
private static BigInteger p = new BigInteger("2");
private int l = 2048

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    DHParameterSpec dhParams = new DHParameterSpec(p, g, l);
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH", "BC");

    keyGen.initialize(dhParams);
```

it seems `l`param works wrong or I misunderstood it and don't know how to fix it.
Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the 'l' parameter (also 'p' and 'g'). Firstly, it is optional, so you can just use new DHParameterSpec(p, g). Secondly, when used it is typically much shorter than the bit length of 'p' (which is supposed to be the prime modulus, not "2"), e.g. in [RFC 7919](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7919), Appendix A.1. specifies a 2048-bit modulus 'p' and a generator 'g' = "2", for which the suggested minimum 'l' value is 225. That means that it is considered secure to choose a secret exponent (private key) only 225 bits long, which speeds up key generation and DH operations significantly.

I would probably recommend that you just use that parameter set from RFC 7919.

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting is KeyPairGenerator::initialize(int), where the int is the size of the key to generate.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html#initialize(int)

Comment: i have a preset of P and , also this method works too long on mobile